# How to add dots in slide

Tags: javascript, slider

Im using tihs for the slider how to add radio button for the slider

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#owl-example').sliderPro({
        width: '100%',
        buttons: false,
        slideDistance: 0,
        touchSwipe: false,
        autoplay: false,
        keyboard: false,
        breakpoints: {
            1920: {
                height: '800px',
            },
            1600: {
                height: '650px',
            },
            1024: {
                height: '590px',
            },
            720: {
                height: '360px',
            },
            525: {
                height: '285px',
            },
            400: {
                height: '220px',
            },
            320: {
                height: '180px',
            }
        }
    });
```

i tried to add dots:true, but its not working.is there any other ways that i can add so that the button will show?

Comment: @Pepito I removed the C# tag for OP. Gratuitous tag spam :-(

Answer (score 0):

Change `buttons: false` to `buttons: true`, or remove it.

https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/api.md#buttons

```
buttons
    Indicates whether the buttons will be created.
    Default value: true
```